# How to build a comma separated array in python

Tags: python

I have a list of user id's in a list in python
`['user1', 'user2' , 'user3',...]` 
and i am trying to build an array from these list of user id's and then trying to pass this new array into a shell command in python. I am able to do all the other steps but i am stuck with this building an array thing.

I have tried this so far,

```
my_list = ['user1', 'user2' , 'user3'
string = "user_id="
var = [string + x for x in my_list]
```

But what i actually need is something like this

```
var = "(|(user_id=user1)(user_id=user2)(user_id=user3))"
```

and this list goes for many other values.
I am stuck here how to build this value `(user_id=user1)(user_id=user2)(user_id=user3)` in python.

Can anyone suggest some ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension to generate the subclauses, then join them into a string and wrap it.

```py
my_list = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]
ldap_expr = "(|%s)" % "".join(
    "(user_id=%s)" % user_id for user_id in my_list
)
print(ldap_expr)
```

The output is

```
(|(user_id=user1)(user_id=user2)(user_id=user3))
```

Comment: wow, this works great...:)

Answer (score 0):

Here it will add strings to var.

```
user = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']

var = "(|"
for i in range(len(user)):
    var += "(user_id=%s)" % user[i]
var += ")"
print(var)
```

Output is:

```
(|(user_id=user1)(user_id=user2)(user_id=user3))
```